# How to get the Bullseye achievement?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

What's a good strategy to die exactly on 200m mark? I always end up a few meters too short or too far... Is it just luck?

Comment: It's pretty much luck.  Make sure you don't grab any vehicles at the start, but otherwise just try and smack into something pretty close to it.  If you hit lower down on the screen you'll slide less distance, so you can make it a little more precise.  It took me dozens of tries to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Equip the Freeze-o-matic gadget, fly near the ceiling and hit the first zapper. After about 10 tries you should get it.